point cut advice on controller is not getting attached with current trace id from sleuth
point cut advice on controller is not getting attached with current trace id from sleuth
I have tried with autowire Tracer class and other relevant solutions.
I have also tried with different type of bean initialization and other stuff

Showing code could make people helping you easier, could you please post what code you have tried ?
